# Remove certain type of tag from HTML (without string operations) with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a long html file, and it has a bunch of "span" elements throughout.  (Ie they begin with `<span` and end with `/span>`.  Is there a way with BeautifulSoup to eliminate all of those span attributes and end up with the remaining html?

My alternative would be to use a series of complex string operations to scrub the text before sending it through BeautifulSoup but I would love to avoid that if possible.

EDIT:
I attempted the decompose() function like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml)
soup.span.decompose()
print soup.prettify()
```

and all the  parts are still in there.  It doesn't seem to have altered the html at all.

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract

Comment: @roippi yes I have looked through the documentation.  Some of it is a little hard to follow cause I'm not a professional programmer.  I do the best I can then ask for help when I'm stumped.  I sort of thought that was the purpose of this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is rather easy...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = "<span>Hello world</span><h1>Nice to see you</h1><span>no</span><span>Hello babe</span>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

while len(soup.find_all('span')) > 0:
    soup.span.extract()
print soup
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the method you're looking for is unwrap():
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap

There are many ways to implement this, so how you execute it depends on your particular situation, but unwrap() seems like it should work.

I have done some pretty extensive work with this, check out my post here:
http://bobbyrussell.io/posting-to-wordpress-programatically/

Hope that helps!

Comment: This just removes the tag, but keeps all the text that was inside the tag. I want the whole thing removed, not just the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

" > a series of complex string operations "

actually with regular expressions it is quite straight forward:

```
import re
re.sub( r'<span .*?/span>', '', html_txt , flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: You shouldnt use regular expressions to parse html. It may work for this very simple example, but it wont be a robust solution.